# Writing a Function that will accept any size matrix

Tags: r

I need to write a function that will accept a matrix of any size as an argument and returns true if the matrix is square and false if not. it also needs to work for scalars.

I cant seem to get my function to work on different matrixes as it keeps telling me i have an unused argument which is usually the matrix im trying to put into my function.

Comment: This is a simple function ie `is_sq_matrix <-function(x) NCOL(x) == NROW(x)` is sufficient enough to work in any case

Comment: you can then run `is_sq_matrix(iris)` `is_sq_matrix(diag(3))` `is_sq_matrix(1:3)` `is_sq_matrix(1)`

Comment: `diff(dim(x))==0`  should work.

Comment: R has no scalar types, so what object types you consider a scalar?

Answer (score 1):

An easy function that would return a value only if given a matrix/vector:

```
is_square <- function(x) {
    if(!is.atomic(x)) stop("The input is not a matrix/scalar/vector")
   NCOL(x) == NROW(x)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Short version:

```
testMat <- function(mat){
  # Same number of columns and rows (NROW and NCOL defaults to length for flat arrays)
  if((nr <- NROW(mat)) == NCOL(mat)){
    #' Test:
    #' 1) is it a 1x1 matrix (constant)
    #' 2) Is it a matrix?
    #' 3) is it an array, and if it is an array, are all dimensions identical?
    if(nr == 1 || is.matrix(mat) || (is.array(mat) && all(diff(dim(mat)) == 0))){
      return(TRUE)
    }
  }
  FALSE
}

testMat(1:3) # 1x3 | 3x1 - FALSE
testMat(1) # 1x1 - TRUE 
testMat(matrix(1:4, nrow = 2)) # 2x2 - TRUE
testMat(matrix(1:6, nrow = 2)) # 2x3 - FALSE
testMat(array(1:4, dim = c(2,2))) # 2x2 - TRUE
testMat(array(1:6, dim = c(2,3))) # 2x3 - FALSE
testMat(array(1:8, dim = c(2,2,2))) # 2x2x2 - TRUE 
testMat(array(1, dim = c(2,2,3))) # 2x2x3 - FALSE
```

Comment: R has no scalars, but length == 1 is not enough to consider it a scalar, `foo <- function(x) x; testMat(foo) # TRUE`

Comment: Indeed, everything in R is either a vector or a list (if we dig far enough down). We need more information to know what we'd have to test. Is it a numeric matrix or a character matrix? The question only specifies square matrix. One could add `is.vector(mat) || is.matrix(mat) || is.array(mat)` to catch what I believe would be all cases.

Answer (score 0):

I add this one-liner to the game:

```r
is_square <- function(x) length(x) == 1L || length(unique(dim(x))) == 1L
```

The `length` clause makes sure that a single value is considered *"square"*, i.e. `is_square(1)` yields `TRUE` if this is not intended just remove the first clause. The other clause simply tests if all the dimensions are the same (i.e. square).

---

If the function needs to be more robust to data types you could ammend it by a type check:

```r
is_square2 <- function(x) (is.vector(x) || is.array(x)) && (length(x) == 1L || length(unique(dim(x))) == 1L)

is_square(function(x) x)  ## TRUE but should be FALSE
is_square2(function(x) x) ## FALSE
is_square(data.frame(1:2, 1:2))  ## TRUE, debatable
is_square2(data.frame(1:2, 1:2)) ## FALSE in the strict sense
```

Comment: Technically this would fail on `data.frame(A = 1:2, B = 3:4)`. 

Comment: Well, I would consider that a square "matrix". But depending on the level of type safety needed this use case may be of more concern `is_square(\(x) x)`. So if type safety is needed some more clauses will be indeed necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This will probably work too.

```
MyFunction <- function(x){
  
  if(length(dim(x)) == 2){ dim(x)[1] == dim(x)[2] } else { FALSE }
  
}
```